# Does a file system include executing code or just data structures

Tags: linux, filesystems

Let's take an SD card for example. I wish to partition this card into different partitions with different file systems on each partition, for example FAT, EXT3, HFS etc.

I understand the SD card will have a memory controller. In order for these file systems to work for each partition, will extra code be added to the card, or is it just data structures which get updated?

If we mount this card onto a Linux system for example, is it Linux which has the special code to deal with each file system, or is this embedded into the card, or is there even any extra code involved here for a file system? This concept I haven't fully grasped yet.

Comment: Interpreting the FS is entirely up to the OS. Linux has support for many different filesystems to allow this. There is no code executed by the SD card/reader itself. It's easy to tell because Linux `ext4` formatted SD cards don't work on Windows.

Comment: Think about it: if the SD card had executable code, it would only work with a computer and OS that can execute that code, you wouldn't be able to swap it between different operating systems, different CPUs, etc.

Comment: @Barmar How does the memory controller on the SD card work then? When we wish to partition the card and format it etc. don't we communicate with the SD card memory controller. This will be a computer of its own I guess

Comment: There's a standard protocol for communicating with SD cards, just like most other storage devices.